# How to prevent button click event

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-directive

I create a is-login.directive

```
<button type="button" appIsLogin (click)="sayHello()">
 down
</button>
```

component

```
  sayHello() {
    console.log('clicked');
}
```

is-login.directive.ts

```
import {Directive, HostListener} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
selector: '[appIsLogin]'
})
export class IsLoginDirective {

isLoginIn = false;

constructor() {
}

@HostListener('mousedown', ['$event'])
onClick(event: Event): boolean {
    if (!this.isLoginIn) {
        console.log('mousedown');
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Current behavior
When I clicked the button, both events happened.I hope click event does not happen.

[console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TTBM3.png)

**I want to monitor the user's click event by the directive, if the user is not logged in, do not execute the click event.**

Comment: Under what circumstances do you want to prevent the click event? If you never want it, just remove `(click)="sayHello()"`

Comment: Are you providing `action` attribute to the `form` element?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
(click)="sayHello(); $event.stopPropagation()"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can disable pointer events:

```
this.elRef.nativeElement.classList.add('disabled');
```

Then in your component CSS:

```
.disabled {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

Comment: element ref should not be used to manipulate the DOM. https://angular.io/api/core/ElementRef

Answer (score 0):

I did it by setting the pointerEvents style to none:

```
import {Directive, HostListener} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
    selector: '[appIsLogin]'
})
export class IsLoginDirective {

    isLoginIn = false;

    constructor(element: ElementRef) {
    }

    @HostListener('click')
    onClick() {
       if (!this.isLoginIn) {
           this.element.nativeElement.style.pointerEvents='none';
       }
    }
}
```